# AppleScript Finder "open using" issue

Tags: applescript, using, finder, tell

I'm having some trouble scripting (what I thought would be) a very easy section of something I'm working on. Basically, I want to tell Finder to open a file with a specific application. Simple, right? From what I've read I should be able to use:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open "the_file" using "the_application"
end tell
```

The trouble is Finder seems to be having one heck of a time finding the application. When I use the following code:

```
set webArcExtract to POSIX file (do shell script "mdfind 'WebArchive Folderizer.app' -onlyin '/Applications/'") as string #Find the Web Archive Extraction Program

tell application "Finder" #Temporary path to save the web archive
    set tempPath to ((home as string) & "temp:")
end tell

tell application "Fake" #Magic that saves a webpage as a webarchive
    load URL "www.google.com"
    delay 3
    capture web page as Web Archive saving in tempPath & "arc.webarchive"
end tell

tell application "Finder" #Open the arc.webarchive file saved in the tempPath with the WebArchive Folderizer application
    open tempPath & "arc.webarchive" using webArcExtract
end tell
```

The values of the variables are as follows:

tempPath: "OSX_Data:Users:user:"
webArcExtract: "OSX:Applications:Utilities:WebArchive Folderizer.app"

The error I get when trying to run the code occurs on the *open tempPath & "arc.webarchive" using webArcExtract* line. A message pops up from Finder stating "The Application cannot be found."

Im really befuddled by this one. I KNOW the path is right and I KNOW the application can open files this way. I can use Finder to go to the arc.webarchive file I'm trying to open, right-click on the file, and select "open with > WebArchive Folderizer" and it works perfectly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple suggestions.
1) an easier method to get the path to an application is to just use applescript's "path to" command so something like this should work...

```
set theFile to (path to desktop as text) & "a.txt"
set appPath to path to application "TextWrangler"
tell application "Finder" to open file theFile using appPath
```

2) You do not need the Finder for the tempPath, again just use "path to"...

```
set tempPath to (path to home folder as text) & "temp:"
```

3) finally you need a file specifier here, so add the keyword "file" before the file path as I did in #1...

```
tell application "Finder"
    open file (tempPath & "arc.webarchive") using webArcExtract
end tell
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Doh! I knew it was something simple. Missing "file" noun. (*facepalm*) Now I feel like an idiot. Thanks for the tip on the "path to" trick as well. Super handy. I'll use that one all the time. I figured there was a better way to do that.

Comment: +1; one subtlety worth pointing out: `path to` doesn't actually return a _path string_, as one might suspect, but an `alias` _object_ pointing to the file; to turn this object into an HFS-format path string, use `appPath as text` (as in the answer), to obtain the POSIX-format path string, use `POSIX path of appPath`.