# AppleScript - What's wrong with my quotes?

Tags: applescript

Hello and thanks for your help,

This is driving me crazy! I keep having syntax errors for simple stuff like just opening a file.

I get > Syntax Error - Expected end of line, etc. but found “"”.

What am I doing wrong? It's the same quotes as the ones for Finder...

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theFile to selection
    open theFile with application "QuickTime Player"
end tell
```

Comment: You need to use `using` rather than `with`, and give the path to the app, not just its name. Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794999/applescript-finder-open-using-issue) cover it sufficiently?

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you for your help! For some reason, I thought you could use call out an app! like tell application "Finder"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected script[1]:

```
tell application "Finder"
  set theFile to selection
  open theFile using application file "QuickTime Player" of folder "Applications" of startup disk
end tell
```

This can be simplified by specifying the application by bundle ID instead of location, in which case Finder will find it for you:

```
  open theFile using application file id "com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX"
```

Or, if you want to do stuff with the file(s) once they’re opened:

```
tell application "Finder"
  set theFiles to selection as alias list
end tell
if theFiles is {} then error "No files selected."

tell application "QuickTime Player"
  activate -- (ensures any "can't open file" error dialogs are visible)
  open theFiles
  -- do other stuff here
end tell
```

--

[1] The syntax error is due to the special behavior of `with`/`without` parameter labels, which expect to be followed by a single keyword (or comma-separated keywords). AppleScript reads the command as `open theFile using application`—and since a command can’t be immediately followed by an expression, in this case a literal string, it reports a (frustratingly unhelpful) syntax error.